# How do I find the minimum number of legal jumps to reach A from 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm having trouble in making an algorithm to solve this question. How can it be done?

Given an integer A denoting the destination position. Jack is initially standing at position 1. At any time if Jack is at position X then in one step he can:

1. Move to 2 *X position.
2. Move to 3 *X position.
3. Move to 4 *X position.
4. Move to 5 *X position.

Help Jack (and me ) to find the minimum number of steps to reach destination position.

If it is impossible to reach destination position using any number of moves then return -1.

#### My attempt

```py
def solve(A):
    currentpos=1
    jump=5
    Jno=0
    while currentpos<A:
        currentpos=currentpos*jump
        Jno+=1
        if currentpos==A:
            break
        elif currentpos>A:
            if jump==2:
                break
            else:
                jump-=1
        else:
            continue
    return Jno
```

Comment: Please add the question as TEXT, not as a link to an image

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider sparing images for pictorial content and have text content inserted as such. Also, while you are at it, you should consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and fix your question accordingly. A honest try, however mistaken, is regarded more highly than no try at all.

Comment: Made the appropriate changes

Comment: This is equivalent to finding the factorization of your number by 2's, 3's, 4's and 5's. Just divide your number by those while possible, if the remainder is not 1, then there is no solution

Comment: Can you explain it properly in an answer @OlivierMelançon I'm really dumb.

Comment: I was just editing my comment, have a look. I cannot write a full answer now, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factors, aside from `4`, which is the square of a prime-factor, are all prime-factors.

Thus, sort them, and try to use each from biggest to smallest as often as possible to retrace the way *back to the starting position*.

```
def minSteps(A):
    Steps = 0
    for X in [5, 4, 3, 2]:
        while A % X == 0:
            A /= X
            Steps += 1
    return Steps if A == 1 else -1
```

It would be more difficult if gcd(a, b) != 1 and a % b != 0 and b % a != 0 for any two factors.

Comment: Why would the high-to-low order be important, aside for the 4 and the 2?

Comment: The order is not really important for correctness anywhere else. But speed of division and remainder are dependent on size of the numbers involved, so getting them small fast helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are already many good answers posted. Anyways, you could try a dynamic programming approach. This paradigm focuses on saving answers to smaller subproblems for use later. I've attached a sample code:

```
A = 100
infinity = 2**32
dp = [infinity]*(A+1)
dp[1] = 0
for i in range(2, A+1):
    if i%5 == 0:
        dp[i] = min(dp[int(i/5)]+1, dp[i])
    if i%4 == 0:
        dp[i] = min(dp[int(i/4)]+1, dp[i])
    if i%3 == 0:
        dp[i] = min(dp[int(i/3)]+1, dp[i])
    if i%2 == 0:
        dp[i] = min(dp[int(i/2)]+1, dp[i])

print(dp[A])
```

**Explanation**: 
`A` is destination--I've just set it at 100 for this example.

I've created an int called `infinity`=2^32 with which I will fill the array `dp`. I assume the question won't make you find a destination greater than `infinity`.

`dp[i]` will store how many steps it takes to reach `i`. For this reason, `dp[1]` is set to 0 because it's our initial position.

I make the size of `dp` to be `A+1` so that `dp` will contain indices from 0...A. (0-based counting)

Now we iterate `i` from 2 to `A`. At every step, we check if `i` is divisible by 2, 3, 4, or 5. If so, we look at `dp` of `i` divided by one of those numbers:

```
    if i%5 == 0:
        dp[i] = min(dp[int(i/5)]+1, dp[i])
    if i%4 == 0:
        dp[i] = min(dp[int(i/4)]+1, dp[i])
    if i%3 == 0:
        dp[i] = min(dp[int(i/3)]+1, dp[i])
    if i%2 == 0:
        dp[i] = min(dp[int(i/2)]+1, dp[i])
```

At each step, in order to find the minimum number of steps to reach `i`, we check to see if we retain the original value of `dp[i]` or replace it with a previous value of `dp+1` because it takes one step to get to `i` from a previous value.

Example: `dp[1] = 0`. Let's say we are now at `i=5`. `i` is divisible by 5. `i/5=1`. Currently, `dp[5]=infinity`. But if we took a step from 1 to 5 (which is legal), we would have taken a total of `dp[1]+1=1` step. 1 is less than `infinity`. Therefore we replace `dp[5]` with 1.

This keeps going until we iterate to `i=A`. Now, `dp[A]` will hold the minimum number of steps to get to `A`. If we can't get to `A`, `dp[A]` will equal `infinity`.

The runtime of this algorithm is linear, O(N).

Sorry for lengthy explanation, I can edit if anyone wants.

Comment: While dp is good for more complex problems, here it is way over the top and thus quite inefficient.

Comment: @Deduplicator I admit there "are already many good answers posted." Just trying to present a different way of thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

If you see this problem in terms of graph , then using breadth first search algorithm will solve this problem. here numbers can be considered as node/vertex and , edges can be considered between this number and the possible numbers you can go from here so if you are at 
 number x and it is a node/vertex, so there is edge between x and 2*x , x and 3*x , x and 4*x , x and 5*x. Here edge cost is same for all the possible edges from a node x (can be considered unit cost here i.e 1), then simply breadth first will solve this problem , stop the bfs when you reach the destination.

for simplicity , we can go in reverse direction , that is if we can go from x to (constant * x) , then we can also go from x to (x/constant)
(if x is divisible by constant value(2 , 3, 4, 5 here)) so start bfs from destination , then at every node go for possible (x/constant value) and keep track of steps  till that node, if you reach a node that is less than 1 , skip the neighbour searching for that node , if you reach the 1 value node , then the tracked steps till that node is the answer so no need to run any more bfs , if you have tried all the node and still hasn't been able to reach the 1 , then answer is -1 , one thing is that to avoid visiting same node repeatedly from different nodes , you can make a visited set in which you can put a node once it has been visited so that in future we can skip a node , if you have already visited it , so total complexity would be O(4*(n)) => O(n) here n is going to be (destination / (smallest constant)) , here smallest constant is 2 , so we can take n as (destination/2) because that is the max number of nodes you will ever travel.

Comment: sounds too complex !

Comment: @KnightCoder about that , do you know or have studied breadth first search ? this is quite a trivial problem once you know breadth first search.

Comment: I have studied BFS and DFS in graphs but I tend to run away from using it. Not a good habit right?

Answer (score 0):

Is this fine? Are there some cases in which it won't work? Any refinements are welcomed

```py
def minSteps(A):
    CurrentPos=1
    Steps=0
    while CurrentPos<A:
        if A%5==0:
            Remainder=A%5
            A=A/5

        elif A%4==0:
            Remainder=A%4
            A=A/4

        elif A%3==0:
            Remainder=A%3
            A=A/3

        elif A%2==0:
            Remainder=A%2
            A=A/2

        else:
            break

        Steps+=1
    if A==CurrentPos:
        print(Steps)
    else:
        print(-1)
```